# classe mysqli não é encontrada

Tags: php, mysqli

O PHP está dando o seguinte erro: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'loja\model\mysqli' not found in`, ele não esta encontrando a classe mysqli, mas eu já verifiquei o php.ini e não está comentado. Estou utilizando o autoLoad do composer, quando eu tiro esse o trecho do código que instancia o mysqli a classe funciona normalmente.
O que poderia ser isso, abaixo irei colocar os códigos

```
 namespace loja\model;
class Banco
{
    public function conectar()
    {

        $con = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","ganha_tempo");

        if($con->connect_errno){
            echo "Erro ao se conectar ao banco de dados";
            mysqli_close();
        }
        return $con;
    }
}
```

classe UserSistema

```
  namespace loja\model\controleUsuariosSistemasModel;
 session_start();
 use loja\model\usuarioGeralModel\Usuarios;
 use loja\model\Banco;
```

class UserSistema extends Usuarios
 {
    private $unidade;
    private $senha;

```
public function setUnidade($unidade)
```

{
      $this->unidade = $unidade;
  }

public function getUnidade()
  {
      return $this->unidade;
  }

public function setSenha($senha)
  {
      $this->senha = $senha;
  }

public function getSenha()
  {
      return $this->senha;
  }

public function logarSistema($cpfUsuario,$senhaUsuario)
  {
    $banco = new Banco();

```
$con = $banco->conectar();

$resultado = $con->query("SELECT nome,senha,cpf,nome_unidade,nome_funcoes FROM usuarios_sistemas,unidade,funcoes WHERE cpf = '$cpfUsuario' AND senha = '$senhaUsuario' AND id_unidade = fk_unidade AND id_funcoes = fk_funcao");

$controle = false;

while ($consulta = $resultado->fetch_object()) 
{
   if($consulta->cpf == $cpfUsuario && $consulta->senha == $senhaUsuario)
   {
    $nomeUsuario = $consulta->nome;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $nomeUsuario;
    $_SESSION['cpf'] = $cpfUsuario;
    $_SESSION['unidade'] = $consulta->nome_unidade;
    $_SESSION['funcao'] = $consulta->nome_funcoes;
    $controle = true;
   }else{
    $controle = false;
   } 
}
$con->close();
return $controle;
```

}

public function controleLogin($cpf)
  {
    if($cpf==null || $cpf=="")
    {
        header('LOCATION:../../../index.php');
    }
  }

public function restricaoAcesso($cpf,$moduloMenu)
  {
    $bd = new banco();

```
$con = $bd->conectaBD();

$resultado = $con->query("SELECT codigo_menu,modulo_menu FROM menu,usuarios_sistemas,acesso_menu WHERE cpf = fk_usuarios_sistemas AND id_menu = fk_menu AND cpf = $cpf");

while($consulta = $resultado->fetch_object()){
      if($consulta->modulo_menu == $moduloMenu){
        echo $consulta->codigo_menu;
      }
}
$con->close();
```

}

`public function criptografaCpf($cpf)
{
    $cripto = base64_encode($cpf);

    return $cripto;
  }


 }`

Comment: Isso é problema de escopo, pois o PHP está procurando a classe `loja\model\mysqli`, dentro do seu *namespace*. Adicione um `use mysqli` no início do seu arquivo para corrigir o escopo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o "use":

```
namespace loja\model;

use mysqli;

class Banco
{
    public function conectar()
    {

    $con = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","ganha_tempo");

    if($con->connect_errno){
           echo "Erro ao se conectar ao banco de dados";
            mysqli_close();
        }

        return $con;
    }
}
```

Ou a barra "\":

```
namespace loja\model;

class Banco
{
    public function conectar()
    {

    $con = new \mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","ganha_tempo");

    if($con->connect_errno){
           echo "Erro ao se conectar ao banco de dados";
            mysqli_close();
        }

        return $con;
    }
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado, resolveu o problema.